# Powershell not creating log file

Tags: powershell, logging

Ive got a powershell script where I am updating alot of stuff and I am wanting to write everything to a log file. I've used a similar method as this to write a CSV file but I can't get this to work. Can anyone help me out on this? Everything works except the log file does not get created.

```
$path = Split-Path -parent "\\srv02file\Public\Information Technology\IT Reports\*.*"
$LogDate = Get-Date -f yyyyMMddhhmm
$LogFile = $path + "Remove_Formatting_$LogDate.log"

#Log function with levels of logging and time entry. Default level is INFO when not set
#LogWrite -LEVEL INFO -Message "Log entry"
#HH:MM:SS INFO Log entry

Function LogWrite
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
        [ValidateSet("INFO","WARN","ERROR","FATAL","DEBUG")]
        [String]
        $Level = "INFO",

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [string]
        $Message

        #[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
        #[string]
        #$LogPath
        )

    $Stamp = (Get-Date).toString("hh:mm:ss")
    $Line = "$Stamp $Level $Message"
    Add-Content $LogFile -Value $Line
    Write-Output $Line
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a trailing slash after the folder in `$LogFile`

Use Join-Path to combine a folder and filename to avoid that issue in future.

You'll also need to uncomment the `$LogPath` parameter and use that, since `$LogFile` doesn't exist in the function scope.